# How do I remap the `Alt+Click` action in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

according to the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) I can add multiple cursors in visual studio code by using `alt+Click` in the editor. Sadly alt+drag is already used by the window manager to move the window around, so visual-studio-code does not get any key events. So how do I change that keyboard configuration in visual studio code? I could not find anything in the default key combinations file.

I am not looking for solution that changes my window manager, I really like that behavior and use it very frequently already for a very long time.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is:
From the top-level menu, click on

> Selection -> Switch to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> for Multi-Cursor

Then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> rather than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>.

You can see where this is in this screenshot: 
[image: You can see where is this in this screenshot]

My VSCode version is 1.24.1

Comment: I tag this as the correct answer for now. But it is not really a solution as it breaks code navigation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved

Comment: Today I noticed a side-effect of this change: the link in terminal is changed to Alt+Click (which cause the original problem OP faced). So at this time either you can only choose one action for Ctrl+Click. For code navigation I can set keyboard shortcut, but for opening the link in terminal, there is no option to change.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no way to do this but already an open [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130) on GitHub which addresses that.

Comment: There is a way now, look at my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375893/4233310)